# I have problems with ownership in rust

Tags: rust, socket.io, compiler-errors

Hello everyone i have a error in rust, i am try call in callbackn function in socket.io lib but i can't. The rust is warning error in call. I areardy try many way to call the self  var but the errro persist.

**I try make this way but don't work**

```rust
           self.socket =Some(
            SocketBuilder::new(
                self.host.clone()
            )        
            .on("connect", |_,_|{
                /*if self.debug{
                    println!("conectado!")
                }*/
            })    
            .on("REBOOT", | _,_| {
                self::Reiniciar()     
            })
            .on("message", callback) 

            .on("error", |err, _| eprintln!("Error: {:#?}", err))        
            .connect()        
            .expect("Connection failed")
```

It is warning error in **self::Reiniciar()**

I change my code **self** to **Game** and now is warning another error

```rust
         self.socket =Some(
            SocketBuilder::new(
                self.host.clone()
            )        
            .on("connect", |_,_|{
                /*if self.debug{
                    println!("conectado!")
                }*/
            })    
            .on("REBOOT", | _,_| {
                Game::Reiniciar()     
            })
            .on("message", callback) 

            .on("error", |err, _| eprintln!("Error: {:#?}", err))        
            .connect()        
            .expect("Connection failed")
        );
```

i ndon't know what i am doing wrong or need make something now i am reading the rust docs and don't fing any solution to this error.

**FUll CODE**

```rust
impl  Game {

    fn Reiniciar(&mut self){
        let document = self.html.document.clone();
        document.get_element_by_id("tabuleiro").unwrap().set_inner_html("");

        let cards = document.query_selector_all("#hand > div:not(#wait) ")
            .unwrap()
            .dyn_into::<web_sys::NodeList>()
            .unwrap();

        let mut i = 0;
        while i < 101 {

            cards.item(i)
            .unwrap()
            .dyn_into::<web_sys::HtmlElement>()
            .unwrap()
            .parent_node()
            .unwrap()
            .remove_child( 
                &cards.item(i).unwrap()
            );

            i += 1
        }
    }


    /**
     * THis function  listem the server to make actions on client application
     */
    fn listen(&mut self){

        let callback = | payload: Payload, _socket: Socket| {        
            match payload {            
                 Payload::String(str) => 
                     println!("{}", str[1..str.len() - 1].to_string()),
                 Payload::Binary(bin_data) => 
                     println!("{:?}",bin_data),
            }    
        }; 
  


        self.socket =Some(
            SocketBuilder::new(
                self.host.clone()
            )        
            .on("connect", |_,_|{
                /*if self.debug{
                    println!("conectado!")
                }*/
            })    
            .on("REBOOT", | _,_| {
                Game::Reiniciar()     
            })
            .on("message", callback) 

            .on("error", |err, _| eprintln!("Error: {:#?}", err))        
            .connect()        
            .expect("Connection failed")
        );
    }

    fn new<T: Into<String>, U: Into<bool>>(host: T, debug: U) ->Self{
        let html = html::html::Html::new();

        Self {
            ultimo: -1,
            jogador: -1,
            debug: debug.into(),
            host: host.into(),
            socket: None,
            html
        }
    }

}
```

**I try change the call to  Game::Reiniciar(&mut self)**

```rust
self.socket =Some(
            SocketBuilder::new(
                self.host.clone()
            )        
            .on("connect", |_,_|{
                /*if self.debug{
                    println!("conectado!")
                }*/
            })    
            .on("REBOOT", | _,_| {
                Game::Reiniciar(&mut self)
            })
            .on("message", callback) 

            .on("error", |err, _| eprintln!("Error: {:#?}", err))        
            .connect()        
            .expect("Connection failed")
        );
```

it is warning error about calls in Reiniciar function.

```
error[E0277]: `*mut u8` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/lib.rs:102:27
    |
102 |               .on("REBOOT", | _,_| {
    |                --           ^-----
    |                |            |
    |  ______________|____________within this `[closure@src/lib.rs:102:27: 102:33]`
    | |              |
    | |              required by a bound introduced by this call
103 | |                 Game::Reiniciar(&mut self)
104 | |             })
    | |_____________^ `*mut u8` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `[closure@src/lib.rs:102:27: 102:33]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut u8`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `PhantomData<*mut u8>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `JsValue`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Object`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `EventTarget`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Window`
```

[Image about this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgJTT.png)

i trying compile this code in wasm. But i am stoping in this error.

Comment: Did you read the error message? Because it doesn't say anything about ownership, or borrowing. It tells you that you're trying to use data which is not thread-safe in a context which might move it between threads. Specifically [rust-socketio requires that event callbacks be movable between threads](https://docs.rs/rust_socketio/latest/rust_socketio/struct.SocketBuilder.html#method.on).

Comment: The second version doesn't make sense, because `Reiniciar` needs a mutable instances of `Game`, which `Game::Reiniciar()` doesn't pass in (hence the error message that "an argument of type `&mut Game` is missing).

Comment: In all honesty, you're trying to muddle your way through rust, and it's just not a language that allows for this kind of things, you're just painting yourself into a corner. And your core problem is a structural architectural issue: you clearly started from an OO-type design where a `Game` object (singleton?) contains an event loop, which uses the game object (so the game object contains itself, indirectly). That's not going to fly, Rust don't like self-referential structures.

Comment: I don't undestand, so i need create another files??

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function as a method, you need to use `.` instead of `::` (path operator):

```rs
self.Reiniciar()
```

You can also call the function from its path, but then you need to pass `self` as a parameter:

```rs
Game::Reiniciar(&mut self)
```

Comment: Sorry none this is working.  Is warning errors in bound  about functions just call in Reiniciar.